# Convert dataframe to JSON using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, format

I have been trying to convert a dataframe to JSON using Python. I am able to do it successfully but  i am not getting the required format of JSON.

Code -

```
df1 = df.rename_axis('CUST_ID').reset_index()
df.to_json('abc.json')
```

Here, abc.json is the filename of JSON and df is the required dataframe.

What I am getting -

```
{"CUST_LAST_UPDATED": 
{"1000":1556879045879.0,"1001":1556879052416.0},
"CUST_NAME":{"1000":"newly 
updated_3_file","1001":"heeloo1"}}
```

What I want -

```
[{"CUST_ID":1000,"CUST_NAME":"newly 
updated_3_file","CUST_LAST_UPDATED":1556879045879},
{"CUST_ID":1001,"CUST_NAME":"heeloo1","CUST_LAST_UPDATED":1556879052416}]
```

Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"C:/Users/T/PycharmProject/test_pandas.py", 
line 19, in <module>
df1 = df.rename_axis('CUST_ID').reset_index()
File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3379, in reset_index
new_obj.insert(0, name, level_values)
File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2613, in insert
allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4063, in insert
raise ValueError('cannot insert {}, already exists'.format(item))
ValueError: cannot insert CUST_ID, already exists
```

df.head() Output -

```
    CUST_ID  CUST_LAST_UPDATED              CUST_NAME
0     1000      1556879045879     newly updated_3_file
1     1001      1556879052416                  heeloo1
```

How to change the format while converting dataframe to JSON?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index and then [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) with `orient='records'`:

```
df1 = df.rename_axis('CUST_ID').reset_index()
df1.to_json('abc.json', orient='records')
```

---

```
[{"CUST_ID":"1000",
  "CUST_LAST_UPDATED":1556879045879.0,
  "CUST_NAME":"newly updated_3_file"},
 {"CUST_ID":"1001",
  "CUST_LAST_UPDATED":1556879052416.0,
  "CUST_NAME":"heeloo1"}]
```

EDIT:

Because there is default index in data, use:

```
df1.to_json('abc.json', orient='records')
```

Verify:

```
print (df1.to_json(orient='records'))
[{"CUST_ID":1000,
  "CUST_LAST_UPDATED":1556879045879,
  "CUST_NAME":"newly pdated_3_file"},
 {"CUST_ID":1001,
  "CUST_LAST_UPDATED":1556879052416,
  "CUST_NAME":"heeloo1"}]
```

Comment: It is giving an error. Please Check post for the error

Comment: I cannot rename the column, neither can I drop it and recreate because the value in the CUST_ID column will change. But if I try just the first approach, it is still giving the error.

Comment: No, I do not want any duplicated column. I want only three columns. Like the one I mentioned in the question.

Comment: df.head() returns top n (5 by default) rows of a data frame.

Comment: CUST_ID  CUST_LAST_UPDATED     CUST_NAME
0     1000      1556879045879     newly updated_3_file
1     1001      1556879052416          heeloo1

Comment: There are only two entries

Comment: Check the question

Comment: @TeeKay - Edited answer by data.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a dataframe to a jason format using `to_dict`:

```
df1.to_dict('records')
```

the outpit would the one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if dataframe has nan values in each row and you don't want them in your json file. Follow below code

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
import json
import argparse



if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--csv")
    parser.add_argument("--json")
    args = parser.parse_args()


    entities=pd.read_csv(args.csv)

    json_data=[row.dropna().to_dict() for index,row in entities.iterrows()]
    with open(args.json,"w") as file:
        json.dump(json_data,file)
```